# Failure to Compile HTMLCollectionOf<Element>

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing an eCommerce app, so I have a popup for user when clicks add to cart which allows user to select the variety and quantity of the product user want to add. The popup includes a select form and a number input. I then have to access what was input into these to show the appropriate information in the cart.

I tried to access the information using:

```
let input = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByClassName('number_input'));
```

But that gives this error:

> ERROR in src/app/layout/products/products.component.ts(93,18): error TS2352: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
>     Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLCollectionOf'.
>   src/app/layout/products/products.component.ts(111,14): error TS2352: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

Failed to compile

Visual Studio recommended that I include `unknown` in addition to `HTMLInputElement` to access the information, so I tried:

```
let input = (<HTMLInputElement><unknown>document.getElementsByClassName('number_input'));
```

But that gives this error:

> ERROR in src/app/layout/products/products.component.ts(91,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
>   src/app/layout/products/products.component.ts(109,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.

This is the code for my inputs. It utilizes a modal from bootstrap

```
<div class="modal fade" id="variedades_y_cantidades" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="bebida_descripcion">AGREGAR {{ bebida.descripcion }}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col"><div class="form-group">
              <label for="variadedes">Variaded:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="variadedes">
                    <option *ngFor="let detalle of detalle_bebida">{{detalle.variedad}}</option>
              </select>
          </div></div>
          <div class="row"><div class="col">Cantidad: <input type="number" name="cantidad" min="1" style="width: 70px;" class="number_input" value="1"></div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERRAR</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onModalAgregarClick($event)" data-dismiss="modal">AGREGAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to access the data without any errors so I can compile the app to run.

Comment: Did you try `<HTMLInputElement[]>`?

Comment: If you are using Angular, You should use [(ngModel)] instead of trying to access the DOM element.

Comment: Since `getElementsByClassName()` can give you a list of DOM elements,  you can typecast it to `<HTMLCollection>`. If you want to process each element individually, you can use `<HTMLInputElement>`.

Comment: `<HTMLInputElement[]>` gives this error: Type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLInputElement[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>'

And Typecasting to `<HTMLInputElement>` is what I tried above that gave me the original error.

Any other ideas? I'm going to look into `[(ngModel)]` right now

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a compilation error because you are trying to cast an `HTMLCollection` to an `HTMLElement`.

Your call to `document.getElementsByClassName()` does not return an `HtmlElement`, it returns an `HTMLCollection`. [Here's some helpful documentation from Mozilla on this function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) You'll need to update your cast and then access the first element of the collection, if it even exists.

```
let numberInputs: HTMLCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('number_input');
let firstNumberInput: HTMLSelectElement = numberInputs[0];
console.log(firstNumberInput.value);
```

That being said, when working with Angular it's strongly recommended to use directives in this case. I would instead use the `[(ngModel)]` directive or build a reactive form to access the value of the inputs.

Comment: I know that it's a Collection, but I thought you could cast it as `HTMLInputElement` to access the inputs. I was following this github article [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10453)

The mozilla link talks about accessing the individual elements, but when I do that I get property 'value' does not exist on typle element
`let input = (document.getElementsByClassName('number_input'));
    cantidad = input[0].value;
`

Comment: using `[(ngModel)]` was an effective fix. Thanks!